# How to convert .MXF files to h264 files

Tags: software-recommendation, file-format, video, file-conversion

In Premiere Pro CC 2017 I get a lot of red frames and errors playing back a .MXF file. So converting to h264 seems to be a good way avoiding these errors. Now the internet is full of 'free' programs that do this for you, but they all seem a bit sketchy. Do any of you know a good program that can convert these files, if possible in bulk?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited to http://video.stackexchange.com/ and is also opinion-based

Comment: That being said...[HandBrake](https://handbrake.fr/) is one I use

Comment: Hi Manly, well I asked video software related questions on here before. And it's more of 'how' question in my opinion. I can edit it if you want.

Comment: This is a software recommendation question, not an "I'm stuck with _____, I've tried ____." question, as our site is meant to answer.  There is a separate stack devoted specifically to video production and video editing is listed right [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as off-topic.  Even if you were to edit it, it should go on the video stack.  I noticed your video questions have a very low answer rate too...Not trying to sound rude, just saying it might help _you_ more too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea about your playback errors, but you should (MXF is a container format, so it all depends on what is inside the file) be able to use the Adobe Media Encoder to convert MXF files to H264. You can see the list of supported file formats here:

[Files supported for export with Media Encoder](https://helpx.adobe.com/media-encoder/using/file-formats-supported-export.html)

Adobe Media Encoder can convert files in bulk with no problem, you can also set up "watch folders", so that it will auto-convert anything you drop in that folder. See:

[Watch folders in Adobe Media Encoder](https://helpx.adobe.com/media-encoder/using/add-items-encoding-queue.html#watch_folders_in_adobe_media_encoder_cs5_5_and_later)

Comment: I'm dumb, I didn't even know AME could convert videos! I thought it could only export ones. This seems to work fine and it processes my videos. I tested the .mp4 in Premiere and no problems! Thanks!